# How to copy wifi kernel from one version of Android x86 to another

Tags: kernel, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver, hotspot, android-x86

I am using Android x86 8.1 rc-2 in my PC. The problem is that WiFi is not working on it. I had even used Android x86 7.1 rc-2 in my PC and WiFi was working on that. How can I copy wifi kernel from that iso to new one

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The kernel modules are linked to the running kernel. This it at all a bad idea.

Maybe it is only the firmware which the kernel module is using (dmesg). There you should compare the relevant kernel boot log. When you found which firmware file is loaded (and they have different versions) you can try to copy them over.

Comment: So, is there anything I can do?

Comment: I added info about the firmware.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the boot logs to compare them.

Comment: And add what you mean with "wifi is not working"

Comment: I meant that WiFi is working but not showing mobile hotspots .

Comment: It is only showing WiFi available near

Comment: Mobile wifi Hotspots? Which you enabled on your phone with tethering?

Comment: Yes, mobile hotspot

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit of a late answer, but if you're using a broadcom adapter for wifi, if you load the driver early it will work (don't know about other type, but you could test). Just add `EXTMOD=b43` to the kernel boot loading options.

Note this does not help you swap the kernel, kernel modules or firmware. You can still copy the firmware from the *system.img* if you wanted to. It's located at */lib/firmware/b43* and */lib/firmware/b43legacy*. But for the 7.1 and 8.1 versions of Android x86 it is the same, so this is just FYI. Kernel modules wouldn't even work if you copied them over, nor will it ever boot with a swapped kernel.